# I need a hyperlink on this rainbow text? HTML

Tags: javascript, html, hyperlink

This is the html code that I use to make the rainbow colored text. Currently, the text does not do anything when you click it and it is very small.  I want to have a hyperlink on the text which opens a new tab with my link. I also want to have the size of the rainbow text to be set at 50px. Thank You.

```
<script>





var text="This is the text"

var speed=80 

if (document.all||document.getElementById){
document.write('<span id="highlight">' + text + '</span>')
var storetext=document.getElementById? document.getElementById("highlight") : document.all.highlight
}

else
document.write(text)
var hex=new Array("00","14","28","3C","50","64","78","8C","A0","B4","C8","DC","F0")
var r=1
var g=1
var b=1
var seq=1
function changetext(){
rainbow="#"+hex[r]+hex[g]+hex[b]
storetext.style.color=rainbow
}
function change(){
if (seq==6){
b--
if (b==0)
seq=1
}
if (seq==5){
r++
if (r==12)
seq=6
}
if (seq==4){
g--
if (g==0)
seq=5
}
if (seq==3){
b++
if (b==12)
seq=4
}
if (seq==2){
r--
if (r==0)
seq=3
}
if (seq==1){
g++
if (g==12)
seq=2
}
changetext()
}
function starteffect(){
if (document.all||document.getElementById)
flash=setInterval("change()",speed)
}
starteffect()
</script>
</b>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
document.write('<span id="highlight">' + text + '</span>')
```

to

```
document.write('<a id="highlight" style="font-size: 50px;" href="website.com">' + text + '</a>')
```

Comment: can you also make it embed code and change the font to comic sans

Comment: Go learn HTML and Javascript. http://www.w3schools.com/js/default.asp, http://www.w3schools.com/html/default.asp